# How to insert DEFAULT value with MySQLdb string formatting?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have run into this a few times now, where I'm trying to insert (or bulk insert) into a MySQL table using `VALUES` without defining the columns explicitly, but there is an auto_increment field I want to let auto_increment, or a generated column that I can't insert a value for.

Specifically, let's say I have a table with three columns, two for numbers and one generated column that's the sum of those numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE `addition` (
  `num_1` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_2` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `sum` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`num_1` + `num_2`)) VIRTUAL
)
```

If I want to insert values to this database with a MySQLdb cursor object `cur`, I can't do:

`cur.execute('INSERT INTO addition VALUES %s', [(2, 2, 'DEFAULT')])`

...because you can't define the value for the generated field "sum", and `'DEFAULT'` here is interpreted as the literal string. You'll get MySQL error 3105: The value specified for generated column 'sum' in table 'addition' is not allowed.

But the same error occurs for any value I could think to put in place of `'DEFAULT'`, for example `None` or `False`.

So is there any way to pass a value in the data section (i.e. `[(2, 2, <something>)]`) to tell MySQL to use the default value for the `sum` column? Or is the only way to define it in the SQL itself, i.e.

`cur.execute('INSERT INTO addition VALUES (%s, %s, DEFAULT)', [2, 2])`

This would be helpful when the table structure isn't known, or is prone to change, and you don't want to hard-code which fields should insert as DEFAULT.

--Edit--

Some clarification post-discussion in the comments, if I were to try `cur.execute('INSERT INTO addition VALUES %s', [(2, 2, 'DEFAULT')])`, this tries to insert the literal string `'DEFAULT'`, similarly for `None`, or any other value I could think of. So the question is really a Python question, is there a field (e.g. `MySQLdb.DEFAULT()`) that I can pass to accomplish this. So the final result would look something like `cur.execute('INSERT INTO addition VALUES %s', [(2, 2, MySQLdb.DEFAULT())])`

Comment: Will using a column list help `INSERT INTO addition (num_1, num_2) VALUES (2, 2)`? Then  the statement will always insert into `num_1` and `num_2` even if the structure changes.

Comment: Can you include the definition for the table?

Comment: Yes, many people argue that you should always include the field list in an `INSERT` to make the intention clear and avoid confusion.

Comment: @Steve Yes that would prevent issues with structure changes, but I'm curious if I can accomplish this without the explicit table definition. That is definitely best practice as Tim Roberts points out.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is just an hypothetical, so the example table is sufficient to demo the situation in question imo. If you need more details please let me know.

Comment: @Eric I believe Tim Roberts is saying you should always include a field list. Without that, structure changes will affect the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @Steve Understood, and to be abundantly clear to someone else reading this post that is definitely best practice, however I'm asking if default fields *can* be handled in the data object, not if they should.

Comment: @Eric I might not be understanding the question correctly. I can try to help. If you do not provide a field list, then you have to provide a value for every column explicitly in the `INSERT`.

Comment: @Steve yup, so that's precisely where the question is, given that requirement, is there any way to handle that with MySQLdb if there is a generated field where I *can't* provide a value? SQL solves this with the `DEFAULT` keyword, which can be included in the value list, but I'm unaware of a parallel for MySQLdb. Per my edit, passing something like `'DEFAULT'` is interpreted as the literal string.

Comment: @Eric Sorry, I don't know of a `MySQLdb.default` or anything similar. You may be able to run a `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name` and then parse that to store the default value accessed, but that seems like a lot of work when you can add the `DEFAULT` to the SQL.

Comment: `cur.execute('INSERT INTO addition (num_1, num_2, sum) VALUES (%s, %s, DEFAULT)', [2, 2])` or `cur.execute('INSERT INTO addition (num_1, num_2) VALUES (%s, %s)', [2, 2])`. Always specify the columns list, always check that the columns and the values amount and ordering matches.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a computed sum column, than handle it on the database side via a generated column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE addition (
    num_1 INT,
    num_2 INT,
    sum AS (num_1 + num_2)
);
```

Then, when you insert two numbers, MySQL will handle the math for you:

```sql
INSERT INTO addition (num_1, num2) VALUES (2, 2);
```

Note that generated columns in MySQL are virtual by default, meaning that the sum won't actually be persisted, by rather would happen at the time you do a select.

Comment: Well put, and a helpful point, however that is already the condition I have in my question. I have updated the table definition to be a bit more clear. I'm not asking how to make a generated field, but rather if it's possible to insert to a table with a generated field without explicitly defining the column structure in the INSERT statement

Comment: @Eric Your premise then doesn't make much sense.  If you want to define the value for a virtual column yourself, then you shouldn't be using a virtual column for that.  Now, a column in MySQL can have a _default_ value.  In that case, if you don't include such a column in the insert it will get whatever value is defined as the default.

Comment: Apologies, I must still not be explaining this well. I don't want to define the value for the column, I want it to retain the default (computed) value, I'm asking if this can be accomplished without defining the columns in the insert statement. E.g. in your answer  you have `INSERT INTO addition (num_1, num_2) VALUES (2, 2);`, I want `INSERT INTO addition VALUES (2, 2, DEFAULT)`, but using a MySQLdb cursor and passing the `(2, 2, DEFAULT)` in the data object.

Comment: The concept of default value for a computed column doesn't make sense.  How can you arbitrarily define what the sum of `num_1` and `num_2` are?

Comment: If I try `cur.execute('INSERT INTO addition VALUES %s', [(2, 2, 'DEFAULT')])`, this tries to insert the string `'DEFAULT'`, similarly for `None`, or any other value I could think of. So the question is really a Python question, is there a field (e.g. `MySQLdb.DEFAULT()`) that I can pass to accomplish this. So the final result would look something like `cur.execute('INSERT INTO addition VALUES %s', [(2, 2, MySQLdb.DEFAULT())])`

Comment: Probably my terminology is confusing, I'm referring to it as "default" because if you were to do this with just SQL, it would be `VALUES (2, 2, DEFAULT)`, where `DEFAULT` in this case is what MySQL sets the `sum` column to if I were to omit it entirely from the INSERT, as in your example